# Why should I not use the Hermitian adjoint in this equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

This is superficially a question about translation operators but perhaps more to do with bra & ket basics.
I've been working through Barton Zwiebach's lecture notes (chapter 6) for MIT Quantum Physics II and there is this line that I don't quite follow:
$$\langle p \vert T_{x_0} \vert x_1 \rangle = \langle p \vert e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat{p}x_0}\vert x_1\rangle = e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_0} \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }}= \langle p \vert x_0 + x_1 \rangle$$
It's the second equality I have a problem with. Now, I get that $ \langle p \vert \hat{p}= p \langle p \vert $ and $ \langle p \vert x_1 \rangle = \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }}$ but something  makes me want to take the Hermitian adjoint and put $$\langle p \vert e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat{p}x_0}\vert x_1\rangle = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} p x_0} \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }} $$ which I know is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it becomes clearer with a slightly different notation: If $\psi_p$ is a (generalised) eigenvector of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ with (generalised) eigenvalue $p$, and $\phi$ another Hilbert space vector, then
$$\langle \psi_p|\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\hat{p}x_0}|\phi\rangle 
= \langle \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\hat{p}x_0}\psi_p|\phi\rangle
= \langle \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p x_0}\psi_p|\phi\rangle
= \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}px_0} \langle \psi_p|\phi\rangle.$$
Note that the scalar product is anti-linear in the first component.

Comment: Thanks - I think I see where I was going wrong. Does it make sense to say this?: $ \langle p \vert \alpha \hat{p} \vert x \rangle = \langle \alpha ^* \hat{p} p \vert x \rangle = \alpha p \langle p \vert x \rangle $

Answer (score 1):

I can't second-guess the voices you hear, but if you wish to act on the ket instead of the bra, recall
$$ \langle p \vert \hat{p}\vert x_1 \rangle =   \langle p \vert   \hat{p}\int\!\! dp'~~|p'\rangle \langle p'\vert x_1 \rangle\\
=\int\!\! dp'~~p'\delta(p-p') \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p' x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }}= p \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }} .$$

What holds for $\hat p$  morphs to  $f(\hat p)$, so take $f(\hat p)=e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} \hat p x_1}$ to get
$$ \langle p \vert e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat{p}x_0}\vert x_1\rangle = e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_0} \frac{e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} p x_1}}{\sqrt {2 \pi \hbar }}= \langle p \vert x_0 + x_1 \rangle.$$

- If, on the other hand, you are really asking whether $ \langle p \vert  i\vert x_1 \rangle =  i\langle p \vert   x_1 \rangle $ is consistent, of course it is.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think I was just forgetting to conjugate twice - see my reply to Janik